# Wordpress plupload is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, file, plupload

I keep getting the following error in the console.

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).plupload is not a function

I am trying to setup a WordPress front end page where logged in users can upload images.

There seems to be something that is blocking this script. It's making me crazy!

It is enqueued. I have function that verifies it is loaded.

```
function my_detected_scripts() {
  global $wp_scripts;
  foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
    echo $handle . ' <br /> ';
  endforeach;
}

echo my_detected_scripts();
```

This function produces these js that are enqueued.

```
ssmemberships_js 
jquery 
q-a-plus 
puzzle_reload 
solvemedia_comment_reply 
parallax 
modernizr 
carousel 
tipsy 
fields 
tabs 
jquery_scroll 
supersubs 
superfish 
hoverIntent 
buttons 
ddslick 
main 
googlemaps 
gmap 
bootstrap 
ubermenu 
admin-bar 
plupload-all 
plupload 
jquery-ui-core 
jquery-ui-widget 
jquery-ui-button 
jquery-ui-progressbar 
jquery-ui-sortable 
jquery-ui-tabs 
jquery-ui-autocomplete 
jetpack-photon 
ngg_lightbox_context 
recaptcha 
tml-themed-profiles 
devicepx 
grofiles-cards 
wpgroho 
wp-jquery-lightbox-swipe 
wp-jquery-lightbox 
wpcom-notes-admin-bar
```

I can't even get the generic basic setup to load.

Here is what I have pasted into the template file for this page.

```
<h1>jQuery UI Widget</h1>

<p>You can see this example with different themes on the <a href="http://plupload.com/example_jquery_ui.php">www.plupload.com</a> website.</p>

<form id="form" method="post" action="/echo/json">
    <div id="uploader">
        <p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#uploader").plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',

        // Fake server response here 
        // url : '../upload.php',
        url: "/echo/json",

        // Maximum file size
        max_file_size: '1000mb',

        // User can upload no more then 20 files in one go (sets multiple_queues to false)
        max_file_count: 20,

        chunk_size: '1mb',

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        resize : {
            width: 200, 
            height: 200, 
            quality: 90,
            crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
        },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
            { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
            { title: "Zip files", extensions:  "zip,avi" }
        ],

        // Rename files by clicking on their titles
        rename: true,

        // Sort files
        sortable: true,

        // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
        dragdrop: true,

        // Views to activate
        views: {
            list: true,
            thumbs: true, // Show thumbs
            active: 'thumbs'
        },

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url : 'http://rawgithub.com/moxiecode/moxie/master/bin/flash/Moxie.cdn.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url : 'http://rawgithub.com/moxiecode/moxie/master/bin/silverlight/Moxie.cdn.xap'
    });


    // Handle the case when form was submitted before uploading has finished
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        // Files in queue upload them first
        if ($('#uploader').plupload('getFiles').length > 0) {

            // When all files are uploaded submit form
            $('#uploader').on('complete', function() {
                $('#form')[0].submit();
            });

            $('#uploader').plupload('start');
        } else {
            alert("You must have at least one file in the queue.");
        }
        return false; // Keep the form from submitting
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm new to using plupload and there has to be something that the start up guide isn't saying. However, the wordpress specific stuff is thin.

Please let me know what I am missing or how I can get this to load? It is on a test server so I can't give a URL.

I know some of the configuration stuff within is not correct but it should still fire plupload.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Just replace all the "$" with "jQuery" in your script and check.

Comment: That did not change anything. Still getting the error: **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).plupload is not a function** I copied this jsfiddle into the template. It works on jsfiddle. Not on the template. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/dependencies/ui/jayarjo/plupload-demos/tree/master/2.x/ui/bundled  Echoing loaded scripts shows plupload as enqueued. What else could this be? It is making me crazy. I also copied the plupload folder from a fresh wp install into the test server. No change.

Comment: OK here is something weird. I take out the enqueue and manually add the links to the js and css in the header and I got it to work. This is really odd. Anyone know why this is? It seems buggy to bypass the normal WP enqueue process and hard code these files into the header. Hmmm can these be loaded in footer instead? Will test that next.